# Dask memory overload

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I have the following code in which gives me the value counts of the categorical variables and the number of NaN values in the column. Its running on a single computer. The data is kaggle elo-merchant competition.

```
merchant_headers = historical_transactions.columns.values.tolist()

for c in range(len(merchant_headers)): 
    print(merchant_headers[c])
    print('--------------------')
    print("{}".format(delayed(historical_transactions[merchant_headers[c]].value_counts()).compute()) + '\n')
    print("Number of NaN values {}".format(delayed(historical_transactions[merchant_headers[c]].isnull().sum()).compute()) + '\n')
```

For the above code I get a memory error. I would like to know how configure dask so that I could run this code. Any clarification on how to fix this issue would be a great help.

The error is as below.

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - gc.collect() took 1.991s. This is usually a sign that the some tasks handle too many Python objects at the same time. Rechunking the work into smaller tasks might help.
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.67 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.91 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.91 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.91 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.93 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.93 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.93 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.93 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.94 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.94 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.94 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.95 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.95 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.95 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.95 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.96 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.96 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.96 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.96 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.98 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.98 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.98 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.98 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.99 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.99 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.04 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.02 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.08 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.08 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.08 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.08 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.08 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.08 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.08 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.10 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.10 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.10 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.10 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.11 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.11 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.11 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.06 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.00 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - gc.collect() took 1.108s. This is usually a sign that the some tasks handle too many Python objects at the same time. Rechunking the work into smaller tasks might help.
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.22 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Worker is at 80% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 3.21 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.21 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.21 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.21 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Worker is at 76% memory usage. Resuming worker. Process memory: 3.04 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.04 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.07 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.09 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.12 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.15 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.15 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.15 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.80 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.80 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.84 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.93 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.94 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.94 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.94 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.95 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.95 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.95 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.97 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.98 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.98 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.98 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.99 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.99 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.01 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.89 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.90 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.91 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.91 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.91 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.91 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 2.92 GB -- Worker memory limit: 4.00 GB
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?
```

Thanks

Michael

Comment: I recommend providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First of all I think I should not have used Delayed method since this is just pandas syntax. Secondly according to the theory dask should take chunks of the data and sum up the number of NA values in the dataframe since the data is larger than memory. However, the error shows that the computer is running out of memory. Would be able to tell me whether my thinking is right or wrong. Have I initiated dask wrong in this code to get this error. I used

from dask.distributed import Client,
client = Client(processes=False), Thanks